# Currency symbol not showing in C# Console application

Tags: c#, string, console, format, symbols

Good day,

I am currently learning C# and wrote a formatted string that should show how much a product costs:

```
using System;

namespace Formatting {
    public class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            int numerOfApples = 12;
            decimal pricePerApple = 0.35m;

            Console.WriteLine(
                format: "{0} apples const {1:c}",
                arg0: numerOfApples,
                arg1: pricePerApple * numerOfApples);
```

[The result in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS9Dr.png)

> 12 apples cost ? 4,20

I have looked at the settings in my regional configuration and everything seems okay there...

I also ran the code in the terminal of visual code itself, searched the web, StackOverflow, and glanced at the documentation without any result.

Thanks in advance for teaching me something new.

Comment: What happens if you put the following at the start of your console app? `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;`

Comment: @MatthewWatson That works! but shouldn't .Net already handle printing symbols without this code?

Comment: Please include your code (we can't debug an image and I'm sure not going to type your pictured code into VS by hand).

Comment: Well the default font for a console tends not to be a unicode font, so I suppose that's why the default encoding doesn't support unicode.

Comment: @MatthewWatson so it could be helped by playing with the settings of the console, thanks for the help!

Comment: @John thanks for the heads up, I'll remember that for my other questions in the future

Comment: No, you can't fix it without using that line of code.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using so far? [.NET 4.7.2 fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TwbDJM) prints everything just fine, [.NET 5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GF8kaN) shows some troubles

Comment: You may also convert the value to currency string by specifying a culture explicitly, like `(pricePerApple * numerOfApples).ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))` if it would work for you