# NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol shows ? in Spanish

Tags: c#

In VS 2022,  this code

```
 Console.WriteLine("Currency Symbol: {0}",
                   NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol);
```

shows me an ? instead of €.

My configuration in Windows is Spanish by default and no other language is configured.

Try with

```
    decimal value = 1603.42m;
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
```

shows me the correct symbol in en-US, but the same for fr-FR that first code.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: all works as expected for me on en-US

Comment: Check this: [Currency symbol not showing in C# Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313257/currency-symbol-not-showing-in-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: It hadn't crossed my mind that it was a code page problem, sorry.